# INSERT conflicted with foreign key constraint for lookup table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Alright I have these two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Card] 
(
    [CardID] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CardID] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Deck] 
(
    [DeckID] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]   VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [Class]  VARCHAR (25)  NOT NULL,
    [Guide]  VARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([DeckID] ASC)
);
```

The idea is that someone can build their own deck using records from the Card table. For this functionality I wrote a lookup table script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DeckCard] 
(
    [DeckID] INT NOT NULL,
    [CardID] INT NOT NULL,
    [Count]  INT NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([DeckID] ASC, [CardID] ASC),

    FOREIGN KEY ([DeckID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Deck] ([DeckID]),
    FOREIGN KEY ([CardID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Card] ([CardID])
);
```

Something I just noticed and altered to no effect on the `SQLException` is the PRIMARY KEY definition within the `DeckCard` table (I based this definition off a lookup table example). But anyways that's the error I get and I don't understand the conflict with key statement at all, because I have foreign key's referencing primary keys. Nothing in any SQL tutorials would lead me to believe this isn't the exact way to do it so I assume this has something to do with VS itself? (again removing the PRIMARY KEY line in the lookup table definition doesn't change anything).

The error I get is:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__DeckCard__DeckID__48CFD27E". The conflict occurred in database "TheMorningStar", table "dbo.Deck", column 'DeckID'

Comment: PLEASE show the complete error message.

Comment: @OldProgrammer System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__DeckCard__DeckID__48CFD27E". The conflict occurred in database "TheMorningStar", table "dbo.Deck", column 'DeckID'.

Comment: It's going to throw one right after that with Table: Card Column: CardID but deck read first.

Comment: can you show us code, without it we can only give guesses not answers

Comment: as for my guess, you're probably linking `Deck` object to `Card` object in C# and then you try to insert one of them probably without "cascade insert" enabled, better first insert the two objects unlinked and then link them and insert into `DeckCard` table or cascade on insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to insert data into [DeckCard] table, the first you have to insert into [Card] and [Deck] table.

After you insert into [Card] and [Deck] table then you get CardID and DeckID to use to insert into [DeckCard] table.

Because CardID and DeckID are IDENTITY columns so you want to get CardID and DeckID then you use SELECT @@IDENTITY.

Ex)

```
DECLARE @CardID INT, @DeckID INT;

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Card]([Name]) VALUES('Name');
SET @CardID = @@IDENTITY;

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Deck]([Name],[Class],[Guide]) VALUES('Name','Class','Guide');
SET @DeckID = @@IDENTITY;

INSERT INTO [dbo].[DeckCard]([CardID],[DeckID],[Count]) VALUES(@CardID,@DeckID,0);
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be occur because of some given situations

1. Relational Table inconsistency ( it means that there can be a inconsistent data insertion while you insert in reference table). To solve first insert Card and Deck tables data and then you have to insert the primary key data to DeckCard table. If you try to insert first Deckard Table, it can be a error or inconsistent data entrance not belonging to other tables throw an error.

   2.From your error message dbo.Deck", column 'DeckID are not included or not match. !!!

I assume that the answer will be helpful.